# Duvidas sobre backup, templates e domínios na Rede Multisite no Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Pesquisei temas relacionados mas não entendi muito bem algumas coisas, poderiam me esclarecer algumas duvidas?

1) Como posso fazer o backup de um site especifico na rede multisite ou não seria possível?

2) Estou acostumado a fazer edições no wp diretamente na pasta do template, porém fui realizar um teste e verifiquei que em vez de uma alteração funcionar em um site somente ele replicou para todos os sites da rede multisite.

3) Vocês recomendam algum plugin para fazer o gerenciamento dos domínios? tentei utilizar o WordPress MU Domain Mapping, mas não funcionou em um video que eu vi habilitava um campo para gerenciar os domínios mais não apareceu no meu.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** O ideal é usar plugins especializados (o melhor é buscar artigos de blogs analizando as opções atuais). Mas para fazer o básico, é só exportar os tabelas específicas de cada site, que são armazenadas com o ID do site. Neste exemplo, mostrando tabelas dos sites com ID 2 e 3:

[image: phpmyadmin]
<sup>(lembrando que as tabelas de usuário são só 2 e compartilhadas por todos os sites)</sup>

E também fazer backup da seguinte pasta: `wp-content/uploads/sites/ID_DO_SITE/`

**2)** No multisite, todos os sites compartilham **os mesmos templates/themes e plugins**. Se mexer em um deles, afeta todos os sites onde é usado.

**3)** Esse é O PLUGIN para gerenciar domínios. Pode procurar por bons artigos, que sei que existem, explicando como configurar o plugin e o servidor. Pode procurar aqui também: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain-mapping